# Robocopy require wildcard, can't exactly specify file name with suffix

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, wildcard, robocopy

I need to write batch script that copy different files with same name from few sub-folders. When i use file name * .* , or "name".*, or *."suffix" everything works as intended, but when i specify "name"."suffix", script copy folders, but no files (yes, name is correct and file exist in source). I tried use robocopy without variables, but result is same. I'm able to finish my work with this restriction, but i'd really want to know why this is happening.

Source code:

```
@echo off
title Copy   
:start
Set /p x=Insert file name: || set x=nothing
If "%x%"=="nothing" goto:error1    
robocopy "source" "destination" %x% /e   
pause
goto:eof        
:error1
echo No file name set, please insert correct name.
goto:start
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i think this is what you are searching.

```
robocopy "source" "destination" "%x:"=%" /e
```